# Add <li> to <ul> and remove <li> that is appended to <ul>

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $(".males-input").on("click",function()
       {
            $(".rform .males-list").append('<li><img src="icon/delete.png" title="REMOVE" NAME class="delete-input"/><input type="text" /></li>');
       });
   });
```

this my query in adding `<li>`

what i want is, if i click the `<img>` that appended to `<ul>` it should remove...
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$('ul.males-list').on('click','.delete-input',function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: this should work fine. can you reproduce the issue in fiddle.

Comment: i want to thank you for accepting and voting yung answer but my reputation is only 3, im sorry, but thank you so much! it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('ul .delete-input').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: please provide your html in fiddle